# UIRefreshControl was functioning but not animating

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UIRefreshControl` that is works really fine, it calls the function when scrolled down but the problem is it's not animating, and I don't see any problem in my codes, is there any other way that I don't see that cause this problem?

This is the result I got now

[image]

As you can see in the GIF, there is no animation on the `UIRefreshControl` but still calls the function,

now here is my code

```swift
import UIKit

class DummyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var arr: [Int] = [1,2,3]
    var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        refresher = UIRefreshControl()
        refresher.attributedTitle = nil
        refresher.backgroundColor = .clear
        refresher.tintColor = .black
        refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(populate), for: .valueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(refresher)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arr.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(arr[indexPath.row])

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
    
    @objc func populate() {
        for i in 1...1000 {
            arr.append(i)
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

How should I know what's causing this problem, and how can I solve it?

PS. I edited my code and the gif result, it seems that the answers and comments are get confused on my first code, so I put a delay before end the refreshing.

Comment: `populate` should complete almost immediately, and you're ending the refreshing in the function.

Comment: @BallpointBen I edited the gif result and code, I added a delay before endRefreshing please check

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to `load`.  Say you would pull data from your database which takes some time. When `refreshing` it would take that couple of seconds and you would see the circle animating. But in your case there is nothing to load really. You just populate it with simple `integers` which doesn't need enough time so the `refreshControl` actually has to `animate`.

Comment: I did the answer that @Frankenstein did, but still I get the same result

Comment: why would you want that animation in the first place ? Why keep the user waiting if you can populate the `tableView` instantaneously ?

Comment: I edited the gif result and code, I added a delay before `endRefreshing` please check

Comment: try putting the for-loop inside the Dispatch-function

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing the animation because the `endRefreshing` method is getting called instantaneously. To see the animation you can put in some delay. Here's how:

```
@objc func populate() {
    for i in 1...1000 {
        arr.append(i)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I just get the same result, but it's much longer to load, it stops at half load, but not animating.

Comment: And as I see on other apps, I think it should be still animating while scrolling down the scrollview, even the function is not getting called yet...

Comment: I edited the gif result and code, I added a delay before endRefreshing please check

Answer (score 0):

You should put some delay and you can use an extension for scrollview if you wish below. So your code will be :

```
import UIKit

class DummyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var arr: [Int] = [1,2,3]
    private lazy var refresher = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        refresher = UIRefreshControl()
        refresher.attributedTitle = nil
        refresher.backgroundColor = .clear
        refresher.tintColor = .black
        refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(populate), for: .valueChanged)
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        tableView.addSubview(refresher)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arr.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(arr[indexPath.row])

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
    
    @objc func populate() {
        for i in 1...1000 {
            arr.append(i)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0) {
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }
}


extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
            topConstraint.constant = -scrollView.contentOffset.y/2
        } else {
            topConstraint.constant = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the gif result and code, I added a delay before endRefreshing please check